# Trying to compute correlation matrix efficiently in python

Tags: python, c++, numpy, bigdata, correlation

I have a very large numpy array of data (100K columns by 7K rows) and I want to compute all the pairwise Pearson correlations (~(100,000^2)/2 = 5 billion correlations) between columns. The array barely fits in RAM so simple methods won't cut it, and I want to do this reasonably efficiently too. Are there any ways of doing this (preferably in Python, although C/C++ would be acceptable as well)? Any ways of paralleling this would be extra helpful too, because I'd like to get it done in a reasonable amount of time.

I have already tried using the `numpy.corrcoef` function, but this only used one processor, and it also threw a memory error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm doing this using the [DeepGraph](http://deepgraph.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) library to run this in parallel. I followed the tutorial they had there to generate large correlation matrices. It's running now and it seems like it will take (only!!) 2 hours on my 8*3.4GHz machine. I'm using most of my 16GB of RAM to do this, but it seems like everything's holding together.

Comment: Do you have any code to show how to go from (n,m) -> (m,m) matrix ?